# Vue Js Directives Being Stripped Out Of HTML

Tags: vuejs2

I have been playing around with Vue Js a bit and want to create a dummy Java EE Web application using it on the front end inside of Eclipse. From what I can discern, Vue single file components are compiled into a single JavaScript file using some build engine like Webpack et alia. I don't want to do that right now. So I've tried to create JavaScript files that emulate .vue files. But for some reason, Vue directives are being stripped out of the generated HTML. Here's illustrative code:

```
/** vuetest.js
* Javascript file that emulates a .vue file, to facilitate easy prototyping within an
* Eclipse Dynamic Web Application without having to compile single file Vue components
* outside of the IDE.
*/

var appTemplate = `
<div style="width:100%">
<div class="div-style"><a v-on:click ="alert('Working...');">Test</a></div>
<div class="div-style-two"><a onclick ="alert('Working...');">Test 2</a></div>
</div>
`;

var style = `<style type='text/css'>
.div-style {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: orange;
}
.div-style-two {
    float:right;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>`;

$(style).appendTo("head");

Vue.component('app-content', {
template: appTemplate
});

var app = new Vue({
el: '#app'
});
```

And:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Vue Directives Test</title>
<script src="lib/vue.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<app-content></app-content>
</div>
<script src="js/vuetest.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All works fine except the v-on directive; it is stripped out of the compiled template. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why the `v-on` is not there

> The v-on directive; it is stripped out of the compiled template. What am I missing?

Vue.js removes all directive attributes after compiling them, so you rendered markup is clean and tidy. ([source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/273#issuecomment-43408252))

So, the `v-on` is just not in the HTML, but **it was** taken into account.

## Making it work

In your case, you will also get an error like:

> VM5894 vue.js:584 [Vue warn]: Property or method "`alert`" is not
> defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that
> this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for
> class-based components, by initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> found in
>
> ---> `<AppContent>`
> `<Root>`
>
> VM5906:2 Uncaught TypeError: `alert` is not a function

This happens because Vue will expect the `alert` to be a method on the component. Try adding `methods: { alert: alert.bind(window) }` to your component declaration:

```
Vue.component('app-content', {
  template: appTemplate,
  methods: { alert: alert.bind(window) }
});
```

The code above will make the component's `alert()` method be the `window.alert()` method.

Check here [a plunker **demo** of this code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ch4n936nD5q0scpXAcUb?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks, acdcjunior. I quess I was anticipating that Vue Js would convert v-on:click to onclick in the rendered HTML. Is there a good resource that explains in great detail how the Vue compiler works (as there is for, say, JSF)?